# Does each form in WinForms have its own thread?

Tags: multithreading, winforms, win32gui

When using WinForms, does each form have its own thread?  Or do they all share a common thread?

I would imagine that the question/answer would also be applicable to Win32 programming since (as I understand it), WinForms is just an abstraction over Win32, but I'm not sure.  If it is, I'll tag the question as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, typically all forms of the same process run in the same thread (known as the UI thread). It is possible to show a form in a different thread, but it's uncommon and can cause all kinds of issues...

*To be more precise: a form doesn't really "have" a thread. It has a message pump, which is basically just a loop that processes the messages sent to the window. And that message pump runs in a thread.*

Comment: Thanks.  This is correct for Win32 programming, right?

Comment: @TimCoker, yes, absolutely. As you mentioned in your question, WinForms is just a managed wrapper around Win32.